# Getting value of ListView using up / down keys

Tags: vb.net

I need to store the value of ItemCode at coloumn 0 of my ListView.
Using the following code in click event, it works

```
vrEditProductCode = lvVendors.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems.Item(0).Text
```

But the same code in `selectedindex changed event` is causing an `index out of range exception`.

Please advise how to fix it.  I want user to get this value when up/down arrow key is pressed.
In datagridview, we can do it like

```
vrItemCode=dgvOne.item(0,dgvitem.currentrow.index).value
```

But I could not do it in list view.  Please help.
Thanks

Comment: I put vrEditProductCode = lvVendors.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems.Item(0).Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this code snippet :

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles    ListView1.ItemSelectionChanged
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ItemIndex)
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Item.Text)
End Sub
```

This should enable you to record items that have been selected.

I would recommend using the `ItemSelectionChanged` rather than the `IndexChanged` because it is more appropriate and easier to use, mainly because you get a more precise `EventArg`, specifically a `System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs`

Comment: Thanks ! This works.  I put vrMyItemValue=e.item.text and it did what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `ListView` first deselects the old selection `lvVendors.SelectedItems` is `null`.

So you need to check first if `SelectedItems != null`:

VB.NET:

```
If lvVendors.SelectedItems IsNot Nothing AndAlso lvVendors.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    Dim vrEditProductCode As String = lvVendors.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems.Item(0).Text
End If
```

C#:

```
if (lvVendors.SelectedItems != null && lvVendors.SelectedItems.Count!=0)
{
    string vrEditProductCode = lvVendors.SelectedItems.Item[0].SubItems.Item[0].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

Private Sub lvSearch_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles lvSearch.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then

```
        If lvSearch.SelectedItems(0).Index < (lvSearch.Items.Count - 1) Then

            txtName.Text = lvSearch.Items(lvSearch.SelectedItems(0).Index + 1).SubItems(1).Text

        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lvSearch_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles lvSearch.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        If lvSearch.SelectedItems(0).Index >= 0 Then

            txtName.Text = lvSearch.Items(lvSearch.SelectedItems(0).Index).SubItems(1).Text

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```